# Faraway objects tremble

Tags: objects, 3d-view

So I have objects that seem to tremble when they're faraway from the world center.
Here's a link to a video, showing the problem: https://youtu.be/8b0r-znOv_A

These animals were imported to the main project a few days ago and back then, they didn't tremble. I can't remember if back then, they were closer to the world center point or not. I may have moved them.
I tried recovering some auto-saves right after I noticed the problem, but the tremble still persisted when I went back to a 2-day old file, which was the oldest auto-save I had. I also don't remember changing any kind of setting in the program.
The same thing happens in other projects if I put the initial cube 360km (360000m) away from the world center, it starts trembling as well. Is this perhaps something normal to happen, just because it's very far away?

I'm also wondering if this has something to do with the update I just did, 1 or 2 days ago, to my graphics card driver.

Here's my computer specs:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X 8-Core

GPU: GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER

32gb RAM

Comment: It's probably a precision issue, similar to https://developer.blender.org/T43835 .  Generally speaking, it's just not a good idea to put things that far away from the world origin.  It's not even a good idea to put things a few hundred units from the world origin for purposes of Cycles rendering.  Is there some important reason for them to be 360km from origin?

Comment: Well, the project has a huge world. And these animal assets are just some side-assets that are ready to be added to the main scene whenever I want. But since they're not being used, they're just faraway in a closed collection. I didn't want them to be mixed with the world, when I activate the collection.

Comment: You should either use another blend file, a different scene, a different view layer or use the collection exlusion mechanic (augmented layers) to achieve this, but trying to precisely place objects very far away from origin won't bode well in Blender. Or most other 3D softwares for that matter